# Unable to enable any APIs in new GCP account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've setup a new free-tier / trial GCP account using my person gmail account. I've provided my credit card and all seems to be set up correctly however, when I attempt to navigate to the Compute Engine > VM Instances in the Console I receive the following notification.

> Compute Engine is getting ready. This may take a minute or more.

This ultimately results in a failure and in the Notifications area the following is reported.

> Initializing Compute Engine for project My First Project
>   My First Project
>   Unknown error.

A check of the Activity page reported the following

> failed to execute google.api.servicemanagement.v1.ServiceManager.ActivateServices on [compute.googleapis.com]
>   Deadline exceeded (HTTP 504): DEADLINE_EXCEEDED

And, I've tried enabling other API's such as Storage and Datastore that all result in the DEADLINE_EXCEEDED error.

I even went so far as to create entirely new accounts with different gmail addresses and credit cards and had no success with those either.

Can anyone point me to what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the Google Cloud Status Dashboard and it appears that this is a known issue.

> We're working to mitigate an issue with project creation and deletion and errors when activating APIs/services in existing projects.